# pip program issue in python

Tags: python

How do I use pip command in latest python????
I entered the code pip install pandas in the terminal but it shows error.

```
Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> pip install pandas
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install pandas
        ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: Remember to [show the full error, as text](/help/how-to-ask), inside code fences. With that said, pip is a CLI command, just like python. You don't run it _in_ python. Additionally, you generally want to run it in a virtual environment, not just "globally for your system", so you create a venv, then you activate that, then you use `python -m pip install packagename` to install the package you need.

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pip install pandas` (or perhaps `py -m pip install pandas`, depending on your OS)

Answer (score 2):

Exit out of the Python Repl with by typing `exit()` and pressing Enter. Or press Ctrl + Z on Windows and CTRL + D if you are on Unix.

After that, enter the command:

```
pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is a Python module which is not supposed to be run like that in a script. You can either run, in a terminal, `pip install pandas`, or call it through Python : `python -m pip install pandas`.

You may have to replace `python` with `python3` and `pip` by `pip3` depending on how these are installed.